# Questions loaded via live refresh miss padding

Tags: bug, design, live-refresh

A picture says more than a thousand words:

[image]

(Firefox, macOS, all latest versions)

Comment: Yep, the `mr4` class is missing on the `<span class="s-post-summary--stats-item-number">`.

Comment: I *did* see this on several sites like [MSE](https://i.imgur.com/9tRDg85.png), [RPG.SE](https://i.imgur.com/A6X422j.png), and [SO main](https://i.imgur.com/S0YXWmG.png). The timestamps of the question that did have padding is "2022-03-28 17:49:50Z" the one that didn't have padding was "2022-03-28 17:51:00Z". However, I cannot reproduce this behaviour any more after reloading the tabs that exhibited the problem. It could be that it's fixed.